# Municipality 2017 shapefile Europe

Tags: data-request, europe, geospatial

Where can i find the  municipality 2017 shapefile of Luxembourg or does someone know a site where I can download shapefiles of updated municipalities in Europe?

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

A simple google of "municipality 2017 shapefile of Luxembourg" gives me this [link](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset/limites-administratives-du-grand-duche-de-luxembourg) which provides [this shapefile](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset/limites-administratives-du-grand-duche-de-luxembourg/resource/e1c4815d-5a6a-4fff-b8f0-adfd8796603d).

In general the http://www.europeandataportal.eu is a good place to look for European data.

Answer (score 5):

If you want an official source for European administrative GIS data, check [Eurostat's website](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data). Eurostat is the statistical office of the European Union. They gather (GIS) data from member states.

You will find among other the [NUTS zones](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts#nuts13) (administrative units), [communes and commune centroids](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/communes#communes13) for different scales. The last reference year is 2013, but the data shouldn't change every year (I'm not aware of any recent change for Luxembourg at least).

Answer (score 4):

A way is to perform an overpass-turbo query on OpenStreetMap data, like this one for Luxembourg: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/n7b and then download the data as geojson or gpx. You can then easily convert to a shp in a GIS. The key-value pair to look for is:
`"admin_level" = "8"`. You can query others subdivisions by changing this number, see possible values on this page https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level

For Luxembourg only, you may also have a look at geoportail.lu, but unfortunately, their server is down since yesterday! see https://twitter.com/geoportal_lux

J.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "municipalities" but as far as I know the reference website for downloading administrative shapefile is gadm.org

Answer (score 2):

Do visit ESRI online services( ArcGIS Online) Type Luxembourg Municipality data, you will find administrative shapefiles. But do check whether data is updated or not. I downloaded all Luxembourg data of 2015 from ArcGIS online. following are snapshot of files
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can download the shapefiles at [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org)
DIVA-GIS is a free computer program for mapping and geographic data analysis (a geographic information system (GIS). With DIVA-GIS you can make maps of the world, or of a very small area, using, for example, state boundaries, rivers, a satellite image, and the locations of sites where an animal species was observed.
DIVA-GIS also provides [free spatial data for the whole world](http://www.diva-gis.org/Data) that you can use in DIVA-GIS or other programs.